# How do solve an Interesting Diophantine Equation

Tags: calculus, diophantine-equations

I would like to know, for what integer values of $x$ makes $f(x)$ an integer for this equation, which I have derived from several other equations: $$f\left(x\right)=0.25x-0.5(33)+\left(\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{33^2}{4}\right)$$ It looks simple, but I would like a definitive answer. I'm leaving the fractions as decimals as I don't know if it would make much of a difference. As I'm studying efficient factorization techniques, I'm specifically interested in methods that do not include factoring integers (as it would be counter-productive to do so).

Comment: May I ask why you are interested in methods without factoring?

Comment: As I am studying efficient factorization techniques, so it would be against the point to use factoring.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us what you have tried. You should start by writing the decimals as fractions and clear the denominiators. I note that this is the most recent of several similar questions you have asked. Where are they coming from?

Comment: @EthanBolker Ok, edited the answer. As for the second question, like a said, I want to create factorization techniques that are efficient and those are the equations that I have encountered in my studies.

Comment: What exactly is so "interesting" about this particular equation?

Comment: Not sure what you want exactly...$f(x)=(x-33)(x-33)$

Comment: @GerryMyerson it just doesn't seem like other equations.

Comment: Wouldn't $y$ be considered to be the second variable?

Comment: You may be correct, I usually see such equations in terms of x,y, z not in the form f(x)=...

Comment: I don't know what "it just doesn't seem like other equations" means, Quote.

Comment: Well, I guess technically, this is a degree 1 equation, isn't it?

Comment: No, Quote, it is not an equation of degree one. "Degree" is a property of polynomials, and what you have there isn't even a polynomial.

Comment: Then what is it?

Comment: Not every equation has a name, Quote. The function on the right side of the equation is called a rational function. By the way, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry into it, so I get notified.

Comment: Oh, ok thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the equation as 
$$ y = \frac{x}{4} - \frac{33}{2} + \frac{1089}{4x} $$
For $y$ to be an integer, clearly $x$ must be a divisor of $1089 = 3^2 \cdot 11^2$; for each of the $18$ divisors (positive and negative), it turns out $y$ is an integer.

Comment: Yes, I realized that, but it is predicated on factoring. Is there another way?

Comment: Well, it's clear $|x|\le1089$, so you only have to test $2179$ different values of $x$, if you really want to do it without factoring.

Comment: I thought by  "without factoring" you meant "without factoring polynomials". Solving Diophantine equations without thinking about factoring _integers_ makes no sense (to me) mathematically.

Comment: Really, how? There probably is a way. For example, linear and some quartic and quintic can be solved without factoring.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I know this isn't the point of SO but I laughed so hard to this

Comment: @QuoteDave Linear diophantine equations are parametrized using Euclid's lemma which uses factorization ($p|ab\Longrightarrow p|a\vee p|b$). For degree $n>1$ you can use a few inequalities and just try finite cases, but this doesn't always work, and you have to find the right inequality, all other ways to solve them is trying to find some $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that you can view the equation modulo $m$ and arrive to some conclusions, but modular arithmetic is built on divisibility and factoring. Even if you decide to factorize just polynomials, you still have to factor numbers to get an answer

Comment: I don't know whom "Really, how?" is directed to, Quote. It would help if you would ping the user you are addressing by including @username in your replies.

Comment: Ok I'll take that into consideration next time @GerryMyerson